# Refresh dynamically generated PHP select options without refreshing

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm wanting to populate the `select` below with options that are added to the `/server/php/data/` folder without having to refresh the page. Right now it only shows newly added files if I refresh the page. Here is my `select`:

```
<form action="/server/php/data/process.php" method="post">
     <select type="text" name="selectTemplate" onchange="loadTemplate()">
           <option value="" selected="selected">Select Template</option>
                    <?php
                         foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/server/php/data/*') as $filename){
                         $filename = basename($filename);
                         echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
                      }
                    ?>
      </select>
</form>
```

I've seen ajax solutions with a timer, but I wanted to see if there was a way to refresh the `select` automatically when new files are added to the aforementioned folder.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to have something listening on the front end for an event notification. If you have something like Vue.js or React, you could leverage that.

Comment: Without a page refresh? PHP cannot do that; since it is executed on the server, you will need to hit the server and then refresh the page to show the changes. You're best bet will be a client-side solution, using Javascript.